# Visual studio code - Intellisense auto complete behaviour

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to Visual studio code. I am using Visual studio code for AngularJS application development. As I am from a .NET development background, I'm much fond of intellisense feature in visual studio code. But I could feel something is missing in this. When I type any Object name, autocomplete box pops up with suggestion, when I select the respective item and press period, the object name is not complete. Example: assume the object name is **SampleObject**. When I start typing "**Sam**", suggestion pop up lists "**SampleObject**". Once I select this name and press period, the output is "**Sam.**" and not as "**SampleObject.**" Any setting has to be added for the expected behaviour? Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+Space opens suggestion pop up. That happens when you start typing the keyword/object name. My query is about the next part. Selecting the items in list and press period.

Comment: What version of VS Code are you running? I cannot replicate this in 1.1.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Also, this behavior, you are finding in which page? like `js`, `html` or all of them?

Comment: I am running VS Code 1.1.0 on Windows 7 X64. I could observe this behavior in js file, I have not checked in other files.

Comment: The above issue is not observed when I press "tab" or "enter"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I posted the same query in VScode git hub issues forum. I got the following reply.

You can add the snippet below to your keyboard shortcut configuration to the VS Code to accept a suggestion and insert the dot when pressing .

```json
{
    "key": ".",
    "command": "^acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey && editorLangId == 'javascript'"
}
```

This worked.

Comment: More information on Visual Studio Code keyboard shortcuts can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_customizing-shortcuts

Comment: Added the same for "space" (also consistent with visual studio).  I don't see any reason to include `suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey` or `editorLangId == 'javascript'` either; just do it, dammit.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020) will make those choices more visible with:

> ### [Status bar for suggestions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/v1_51.md#status-bar-for-suggestions)
>
> The suggestions control can now also show its own status bar at the bottom of the window.
> Enable it using the `editor.suggestStatusBar.enable` setting.
> It makes toggling details simpler, and shows if a completion supports inserting, replacing, or both.
>
> [image: Suggest Status Bar -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/images/1_51/suggest-status.png]
>
> <sup>Theme: [GitHub Light](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.github-vscode-theme), Font: FiraCode</sup>
>
> In the sample above, selecting "`Insert`" results in `Math.floorceil` and selecting "`Replace`" results in `Math.floor`.
>
> The new `editor.suggest.insertMode` setting allows you to configure whether you prefer insert or replace.
> When a suggestion supports both, your preference will be the default.

Note that you also have the setting [`editor.tabCompletion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61145094/6309) to force "replace" to be the default, instead of "insert".