# VSCode how to automatically insert Intellisense suggestions without having to press Enter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-completion, youcompleteme

#### Default VS Code Intellisense behaviour

- User is presented with a menu of suggestions
- User then has to press the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys to navigate through the menu
- Finally user has to confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the suggestion and close the dialog

#### What I would like instead

- Don't need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Suggestions are automatically inserted (and cycled through) by pressing <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
- Pressing any other keys will close the dialog and resume typing

---

*To be clear, I want to replicate the [default behaviour of YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/232#issuecomment-15934327):*

> When you type, a completion menu pops up. If you like the completions, you use the `<Tab>` key (by default, can be changed to `<Enter>` or `<Down>` arrow or whatever) to select a completion string you want. The very act of "tabbing through" the list to select the item you want *inserts* the candidate string. When you tab to a different candidate, the editor code is replaced with the new candidate. *There is no accept key* because by the point where you have the candidate you want selected in the menu the candidate *has already been inserted in the editor*. There is nothing to "accept". You just keep typing, the candidate has already been inserted.

---

**Is such behaviour possible with Visual Studio Code, either by default or through a plugin?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`editor.tabCompletion` option](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_tab-completion) is the closest thing currently available:

> By default, tab completion is disabled. Use the `editor.tabCompletion` setting to enable it. These values exist:
>
> - `off` - (default) Tab completion is disabled.
> - `on` - Tab completion is enabled for all suggestions and *repeated invocations insert the next best suggestion.*
> - `onlySnippets` - Tab completion only inserts static snippets which prefix match the current line prefix.

*(Emphasis mine)*

---

... except that the first `Tab` press hides the suggestion window.

I did some digging about `editor.tabCompletion`, and I found that [closing the suggestion window is part of the tab completion's option original design](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28215#issuecomment-331100953), and that while other users have asked about [an option not to close the suggestion window](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/67795) or specifically [YouCompleteMe-style behaviour](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70532), that this is currently not supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```

To disable **Enter** to accept suggestion.